# Disclinations, dislocations, lattices, Displacement fields and scaling

Tags: mathematical-physics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, lattice-model

I am looking up Frank, and [Burger vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_vector) and associated material on [dislocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation)/[disclination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclination). It seems straightforward describing a lattice and what dislocation means. It is even possible to restrict broken periodicity only to a line in the modified structure.

However I have a question. If I chose to scale the entire thing say by some factor a, how do I account for an impurity of the form say  $X \rightarrow X + w(X)$ . $w(X)$ here I think is sometimes referred to as  a displacement field.

I think what I want to know is how to do a global lattice scaling that takes into account the implications of such a field.

I have done extensive searching around. It seems rather simple but the displacement really puts me down. I have considered stacking and somewhat creating an effectively same problem by gluing together lattices, but it's not working. It turns out that there are cool mathematical implications of this, however I have not found any reference about the scaling problem.

Comment: Crossposted to http://mathoverflow.net/q/181765/13917

Comment: recently added some illuminating commentary on the math-overflow version of the  problem.